# Prove continuity of function

Tags: continuity

So I have the function:
$$f:\left[-1,2\right]\:\bigcup \left\{3\right\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
$$f\left(x\right)\:=\:x,\:for\:x\in \left[-1,2\right]\:and\:f\left(x\right)=7,\:for\:x\:=\:3$$

And I have to prove continuity in point $x=3$
I know the function is continuous in that point, since it's an isolated point. However, I have to prove continuity using the definition.
That means I must prove that for any sequence $\left(x_n\right)$ with $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(x_n\right)=x_o$ we have $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(f\left(x_n\right)\right)=f\left(x_o\right)$
I was thinking of having $\left(x_n\right)\in \left[-1,2\right]\:and\:\left(v_n\right)\in \left\{3\right\}$ and then proving that the limits of those two as n approaches infinity are equal and equal to $f(3)$, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The only sequence $x_n$ in the domain that converges to $x_o=3$ is the (eventually) constant sequence $x_n=3$

Comment: @GoodDeeds Tail constant, to be precise.

Comment: Yes edited it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

1. You only need to prove that for every sequence **of elements from the domain of $f$**.
2. All sequences with elements from the domain of $f$ which converge to $3$ are constant from some point on.